# Outlook VBA macro to dismiss all overdue calendar reminders

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar

The following VBA code dismisses all overdue reminders in Outlook:

```
Public Sub Dismiss_Only_Overdue_Calendar_Reminders()

    Dim objRem As Reminder

    For Each objRem In Application.Reminders
        If objRem.IsVisible = True Then
            objRem.Dismiss
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

How do I modify it so that **only overdue calendar appointments** are dismissed?

My assumption was either that there was a method which would return the type of reminder (`olAppointment`) or I could get the object that the reminder refers to and check its class. However in both cases, I've struggled to find anything.

I would like reminders triggered by tasks and emails to be untouched.

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is no connection through Parent.

You could set a category or append something to the subject.

```
Public Sub Dismiss_Only_Overdue_Calendar_Reminders()

    Dim objRem As Reminder

    For Each objRem In Application.Reminders
        If objRem.IsVisible = True Then
            Debug.Print objRem.Caption
            Debug.Print objRem.Parent.Class
            'Debug.Print objRem.Parent.name
            Debug.Print objRem.Parent.Parent.Class
            Debug.Print objRem.Parent.Parent.name

            ' Manually or automatically enter a unique string in subject
            If InStr(objRem.Caption, "Cal: ") Then
                objRem.Dismiss
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/olobjectclass-enumeration-outlook